# What is the origin of -oid in ‘factoid’?

Tags: etymology, morphemes

I was thinking about the words ‘factoid’ (a statement based on assumption) and ‘fact’. Are these words unrelated or is -oid a bound morpheme in this case? If it is a morpheme, what exactly does -oid mean and what is its origin? I wonder if words like ‘humanoid’ and ‘cannabinoid’ are related.

Comment: According to the OED, it was already a suffix with this meaning ('similar to, resembling') in classical Greek. This meant that many borrowings from Greek came with pre-morphologized terms good for description. Especially in Greek and Latin, like biologists do. Each borrowing field (chemistry, biology, linguistics, anthropology,etc) had its own conventions about what kind of 'resemblance' was important. So _humanoid_ may refer to the shape or the biological endowment or the behavior of whatever's described that way.

Comment: Could you put that in an answer so that we can comment separately on your information? Thanks!

Comment: No, because I didn't check any resources. I don't know all the details and thus I shouldn't publish or be quoted about it.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/-oid?ref=etymonline_crossreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Factoid* is rare word in that it's a relatively popular recent coinage, but unlike most slang, can be traced to a single, possibly uncontested point of origin:

> The earliest record of factoid comes in 1973, in *Marilyn*, a book that was a combination of photographs of Marilyn Monroe and biographical text provided by [Norman] Mailer. Shortly after using the word Mailer helpfully added an explanation: “...that is, facts which have no existence before appearing in a magazine or newspaper, creations which are not so much lies as a product to manipulate emotion in the Silent Majority.”

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/some-facts-about-factoids

Prescriptivism isn't going to serve us well here - I'm not going to say that the definition you've provided is *wrong*, but it is not the definition used by the word's originator.  When Mailer chose the *-oid* suffix, he did so in accordance with his definition of the word.

Trying to explain Mailer's thinking, *Merriam-Webster* suggests,

> [*factoid*] hails from a long line of words created through adding the suffix -oid, which comes from the ancient Greek eidos, meaning “appearance” or “form."

(ibid)

A key point, which this article hints at, but does not state, is that *-oid* words often describe a thing which resembles, but is not actually some other thing.  This is not always the case.  Cannabinoids *are* present in cannabis; the deltoid muscle really is (roughly speaking) a triangle; *amoeboid* and *amoeba* are used interchangeably.  But consider that an asteroid is *like* a star, but is not one; an android is an imitation man; something that is humanoid is similar in form to a human.  Likewise, a factoid resembles a fact, in that it's an idea that people think is true, but it is not.  Or at least, that's what Mailer was probably thinking when he made up the word.

Comment: Very informative! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

-OID Meaning: "like, like that of, thing like a ______," from Latinized form of Greek -oeidēs (three syllables), from… See definitions of -oid.
from https://www.etymonline.com/word/-oid Find out more at etymonline.com

Comment: The thing is, ‘factoid’ has a somewhat dissimilar meaning to ‘fact’. It seems out of place to add -oid to fact given the meaning you’ve highlighted.

Comment: @kandyman - A "factoid" is kind of like a fact.

Comment: Not quite, since a factoid is an unsupported statement. Something is either a fact or it isn’t. Maybe it’s an erroneous use of -oid.

Comment: @kandyman - Maybe an erroneous use of "fact"?  (Nah, that never happens!)

Comment: The point is that a factoid is **not** a fact, though it's taken as fact and resembles facts in form if not in veracity. So it is an exact use of _-oid_ 'similar to, resembling'. Factoids resemble facts; how do you resemble a fact? By being false, but looking like a fact might look. That's what the suffix means.

Comment: @JohnLawler I see! Thanks a lot for that.